# What is the definition of a Godel numbering of formulas?

Tags: logic, reference-request

Suppose we are given a countable alphabet $A$ of symbols, and we are given the Kleene closure $A^*$ of $A$. We want to assign a Godel number to every word in $A^*$, given a Godel numbering of $A$ itself. The trouble is, different people might use different Godel numberings. I know Kurt Godel himself used prime factorizations in the numbering, but someone else (such as Douglas Hofstadter, in his famous book *Godel, Escher, Bach*) could use decimal concatenation instead as the method of Godel numbering. In other words, there are different ways to map formulas to numbers given a numbering for the alphabet. So, my question really is, what is the formal definition of a Godel numbering $G$ given a numbering for the base alphabet? Well, for one thing, it has to be an injective function, and also computable. But has anyone, in some paper or book, formalized the notion of a Godel numbering?

Comment: It must be A computable function with the key characteristic that, given a number n, we can check if it is a code and, if yes, decode it to retrieve the formula.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA And that is all? No other restrictions? Also, I would like some references for a possible formalization of Godel numbering.